# Sum of elements in js

Tags: javascript, html-table, sum

I need to find the sum of aa[column] and mq[column] together and display the value under Total:
[image]
Please find the jsp code.

```
<tr ng-repeat="aa in validateSeqDataDTOAA">
    <td ng-repeat="column in columns"><b>AA:--</b>{{aa[column]}}</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="mq in validateSeqDataDTOMQ">
    <td ng-repeat="column in columns"><b>MQ:--</b>{{mq[column]}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: If you need to do it then why don't you code it? do you know any javascript?

Comment: I do not think I would be asking for help if I knew how to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do it, is in javascript instead of DOM. Will be something like

```
<tr ng-repeat="aa in validateSeqDataDTOAA">
 <td ng-repeat="column in columns"><b>AA:--</b>{{aa[column]}}</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="mq in validateSeqDataDTOMQ">
 <td ng-repeat="column in columns"><b>MQ:--</b>{{mq[column]}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td ng-repeat="data in totalData">{{ data[$index] }}</td>
</tr>
```

Your Controller code will be something like, considering both validateSeqDataDTOAA and validateSeqDataDTOMQ of being the same length

```
$scope.totalData = [];
$scope.getTotal = function() {
  for (var i in $scope. validateSeqDataDTOAA) {
    for (var j in $scope.columns) {
       if (i == j) {
         $scope.totalData[i] = $scope.validateSeqDataDTOAA[i][j] + $scope.validateSeqDataDTOMQ[i][j];
       }
    }
  }
}
$scope.getTotal();
```